# SP 2013 Missing timer jobs: Information policy management and Expiration policy timer job

Tags: timer-jobs, jobs

Creating record centre site for one of our web applications. 'Information policy management ' and 'Expiration policy' timer jobs are missing from job definitions for this perticular web app. I see this issue only in production environment.
Already tried to restore the jobs by EnsureDefaultJobs() But failed. Deleting web application is not an option. How possibly these jobs could be restored?

Comment: Did you ran the command against web app or farm? Also did you try to clear config cache on SharePoint servers? How you provision the web app?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that

> Library and Folder Based Retention

feature is activated

You can go to Top level site settings

> ->Under Site Collection Administration->Site Collection policies->Activate "Library and Folder Based Retention".

[Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0989ed09-5495-4e59-b99d-2605ef0c14a2/information-management-policy-retention-not-working?forum=sharepointgeneral)